# mscorelib.dll throwing System.NullReferenceException when using async / await

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to write an API Post method using async / await, and I'm getting a run-time error during debug:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

The debugger always fails after stepping over the "await" line.  It doesn't even make it to the catch block. The debugger just exists.

Here's my code:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> DoPost(int ID)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //POST/GET
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myapidomain.com/api/endpoint");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "my key goes here");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                        .Accept
                        .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    StringContent payload = new StringContent("{\"id\":\"123\"}"); 
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, payload); 

                    return new JsonResult { Data = false };
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                return new JsonResult { Data = false };
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well I think you should fix the first `return` to be `return new JsonResult { Data = response };` or something else. Otherwise your code could be refactored to the one line method `return new JsonResult { Data = false };`.

Comment: the content of the return is irrelevant - I'm not using the result in any way.  The method errors prior to the return.  But all things being equal it would throw the same error even if the return was {Data = response }

Comment: On attempt of the actual code given, I cannot reproduce a `NullReferenceException`.  What version of .NET are you targeting? Are you taking `HttpClient` from the framework, or from a nuget package? 
 If the latter, which version?  Do you get the NRE when running your app outside of the debugger?  Which IDE and version are you using?  Can you reproduce in a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.3.2 |
Microsoft.NET Framework Version 4.6.01055 |
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.30726.0 |
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.50601.0

Comment: I've refactored the code as suggested, making HttpClient a static member and such..  same issue.  However; I've tried setting it up as a console application and I DO NOT run into the same issue.  So it seems as though it's specific to debugging a web application (as of now).

Comment: I suppose you are running on ASP.NET? Since you're not using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, the continuation of your call will be posted on the synchronization context. The synchronization context will throw a NullReferenceException exception if the request has already ended for some reason. I don't know what code is executing ahead of `DoPost`, but somewhere you're ending the request before the method is complete. Maybe you're not using an async action in your controller?

Comment: @EyalZinder did you find any solution to your problem? I came across this few days ago and cannot find any solution. It is happening only in web application, the exact same code is running without any problem in winforms or console app.