# mscorlib.dll throws 'System.NullReferenceException' when using SendAsync() function in ASP.NET 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, .net-4.7.2

I have a web application (ASP.NET 4.7.2, C#). I am using HttpClient to do a POST request to webservice.
When it comes to the point to execute this  `response = await client.SendAsync(request);`

it throws
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

I wrapped it around a try/catch but the exception doesn't get cought.

The **exact same code** works perfectly on WinForms App and on a Console project (!!).

Here is the exception that i get

```
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task&amp;amp; currentTask)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c.&amp;lt;ThrowAsyncIfNecessary&amp;gt;b__18_0(Object s)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Δεν έχει οριστεί αναφορά αντικειμένου at μια παρουσία αντικειμένου.
   at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task&amp;amp; currentTask)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c.&amp;lt;ThrowAsyncIfNecessary&amp;gt;b__18_0(Object s)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

And here is the stripped down code

```
public async Task<bool> SendPostRequestAsync()
{
    string endpoint = "endpointname";
    url = endpointUrl;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

    // adding Request headers for authentication
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(...);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(...);
    var uri = url + endpoint + "?" + queryString;

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyxml);
    using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
    {
        try
        {
            Uri myUri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute);
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = myUri,
                Content = content
            };

            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
            
            //this is to check if there nothing is null for the action
            bool iAmOk = ((client != null) && (response != null) && (url != null) && (request != null) && (bodyxml != null));
            if (!iAmOk) { return false; }
            
            try
            {
               response = await client.SendAsync(request);
               //here throws the exception
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
                //it never goes here
            }
            var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // the call is successfull
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Error("errordata");
                //the call is not successfull
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            //it doesn't go neither here
            _log.Error("exceptiondata");
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

I am using

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.29
- ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.11.116.46506
- ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.11.116.46506
- .Net Framework 4.7.2

Is it a problem with the type of the application? Or with some libraries ??
(found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818277/mscorelib-dll-throwing-system-nullreferenceexception-when-using-async-await) that looks similar  but does not have any answer yet.
Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: try to update your project to 4.8, and clear all project temp (.NET Temporary folder). then clean, and rebuild. see if it helps

Comment: Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net and read the "Before Getting Started" section. Excerpt: *Tip: If you’re seeing odd behavior or exceptions, and your call stack includes LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext, your application is running in this quirk mode. LegacyAspNet­SynchronizationContext isn’t compatible with async; you need the regular AspNetSynchronizationContext on ASP.NET 4.5.*

Comment: @iSR5 tried to upgrade to 4.8, clean project temo and clean & rebuild but still the same. Application enters break mode in this line  response = await client.SendAsync(request);

Comment: @athskar try to change it to synchronous method instead and check? `client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: @iSR5 yes did that also. didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue in your code is that you are initializing the `HttpResponseMessage` variable `response` before making the asynchronous call, and then later trying to read from it. However, since the exception is thrown during the `SendAsync` call, it's possible that the `response` is still `null` at that point.

You can try to initialize `response` inside the `try` block, just before making the asynchronous call. This ensures that it's not `null` when you try to access it:

Eg.

```
//...

HttpResponseMessage response = null; // Initialize to null here

byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyxml);
using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
     try
     {
        //...

        // Initialize response here
        response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception comes from `System.Threading` namespace I'd assume there is some issue with async/awaits. Also, each framework has different thread management (*synchronization context* to be more precise), it's not strange that code works properly in CLI and WinForms, while fails on ASP.NET

In your code, there is a code smell, which is very suspicious:

```cs
var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This is a synchronous wait in asynchronous method - a big no-no. Depending on internal implementation of this method and how Synchronization Context works in ASP.NET it might cause deadlocks or other failures. Please, in async methods use await call:

```
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I hope this will fix the issue

Comment: tried this but unfortunately it didn't  change anything

Comment: @athskar I see, but still keep it with await as it's both more reliable and has better performance than .Result in async method

Answer (score 0):

> I wrapped it around a try/catch but the exception doesn't get cought.

This almost always is caused by a missed `await` somewhere in the chain of calls above the point the exception is thrown. `try { .. } catch { .. }` wont work or breakpoint inside an `async` method, if anything in the calling chain *above* isn't doing a proper `await`.

I would start by working your way up the call stack and quadruple check you didn't accidently miss `await`ing a Task somewhere. Quite often you will realize you passed a `Task<T>` instead of a `T` into a generic method.

Common example is when you do something like `Deserialize(someObject)`, you can accidently pass in your `Task<YourClass>` into the that method instead of `YourClass`, because the method just takes in a generic `object` so it won't throw a compiler exception.

But when you run the code, you get your issue, the exceptions fail to catch and everything breaks, because your `Task` isn't getting `await`ed

Comment: Checking the code, I found out that there is a button on my page that onclick does the "sendData".  This function calls the "SendPostRequestAsync()" WHITHOUT await.  It has _= SendPostRequestAsync()  instead of await SendPostRequestAsync().

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Each one helped me understand my problem better.

After days of working on this I figured it out.

In my .aspx file I had a button that triggered the whole process:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="button1" data-uk-tooltip="{pos:'left'}" title="start posting data" OnClick="button1_Click" class="md-fab md-fab-accent md-fab-wave"  >
             <i class="material-icons">cloud_upload</i>
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

The  `protected void button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)` had in it this code

```
_ = myClass.RunSendAsync(var1,var2);
```

which was calling the `public async Task<bool> SendPostRequestAsync()` *(from my question)* BUT as I can understand this did not await the SendPostRequestAsync().

Tried these:

1. Updated the project to .NET Framework 4.8 - didn't change much
2. Cleaned temp files from .NET Temporary folder, cleaned solution and rebuilded  - nothing changed
3. Initialized the response inside the try block, before making the asynchronous call - still got the error
4. Changed `var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`  to `var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`  - still got the same error
5. Changed the `button1_ClickAsync` to be async - I got a compiler error "The button1_ClickAsync has a wrong return type"

Finally,
I changed the the `LinkButton` to `anchor` and then made the async call from jQuery AJAX

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-7",
            url: 'myurl/asyncmethod()',
            async: true,
            data: "{'var1':'value1'}",
            success: function (response) { //dothings
                },
            error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
});
```

And created a new WebMethod in my .cs file which calls AND awaits the `myClass.RunSendAsync(var1,var2);`

```
[WebMethod]
public static async void myAsyncMethod(string var1)
{
  //...
  await myClass.RunSendAsync(var1,var2);
  // ...
 }
```

and this worked like a charm!

UPDATE:

When i change the return type of the WebMethod from `void` to `Task<List<Results>>` and debug after the `response = await client.SendAsync(request);` it just stops and does not continue.

what can be wrong there?

Comment: For change 5 in your post above, did you also make it's return type a `Task`? It should be `public async Task button1_ClickAsync(...) { ... }`

Comment: @SteffenColeBlake yes, and I got this error:  `CS0407:  'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Project1.Class.Index.button1_ClickAsync(object, System.EventArgs)' has a wrong return type`